# How many items can the supply convoy hold?

Tags: fire-emblem-awakening

I can't seem to find any information (in-game or online) about the capacity of the supply convoy, and I'm accumulating a lot of equipment that might not get used up anytime soon.

Comment: In past Fire Emblems it was 100. However I have not played Awakening yet so I cannot say to this game specifically.

Comment: @AdamP: It's probably more than that--Path of Radiance allows 200 items, and Radiant Dawn has three convoys that later combine to allow 300 items (http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Supply_Convoy)

Comment: I'm sure there is one but I have no idea what the upper limit could be. I can safely say it's well over 300.

Comment: @Tony: Note that the inventory listing in the game contains items held by all characters as well as the contents of the supply convoy.

Comment: Though the number stops going up at 99, there doesn't seem to be a max limit. So if you have 99 Javelins stored and buy 20 more, you'd have to equip 21 Javelins before the convoy would display 98.

Comment: @Krazer While this is true, I think he's referring to the convoy itself not the item stacks.

Comment: What I like about FE Awakening is that it allows combining multiple partially-used items.  For example, if two units have Iron Swords, one with 15/40 and the other with 20/40, they will combine to a single Iron Sword with 35/40 when both are stored into the convoy.  This applies to restocking as well. If there an Bronze Lance with 40/50 in the convoy and a unit has 35/50 on his Bronze Lance, the weapon is topped off to 50/50 on restocking, with the one in the convoy reduced to 25/50.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my experience, the convoy is intended to have unbounded capacity.  Of course, there are technical constraints, but the game doesn't provide any provisions primarily intended to handle a "convoy full" condition.

Answer (score 2):

I have played a lot of different games, but I have only played Fire Emblem Awakening, Fates: Birthright, Fates: Conquest, Fates: Revelations, and Echoes, but while there are definitely caps in many games, I haven’t found one in Awakening yet. At least in terms of inventory. Max gold is 999,999. Max level is either 20 or 30 depending on what class the character is. My convoy is 277 in swords, 258 in lances, 242 in axes, 250 in bows, 339 in tomes, 89 in staves, 29 in stones, and 381 in items. That’s 1,865 in total. I didn’t even include the items that had any uses on them or were equipped to a character. I don’t think it’ll be easy to cap your convoy. Now excuse me while I restock my convoy with more items.